# Java-Serializing member arrays

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, copy

I have a Position class that I serialize between multiple clients and a server. I have a class called GameWorld that contains arrays of object positions.  For example, the player positions are an array of Positions. Each client has its own GameWorld instance, and so does the server.

On the client side, the client's player Position is serialized and sent to the server. On the Server side, an array of 4 Positions records the positions of the 4 players and sends the positions of the 3 other players to each player. When I serialize a position or an array of positions directly from the GameWorld class, every ObjectInputStream Position or Position[] seems to retain its initial value, with no regard to player movement.

HOWEVER, if I make a new Position or Position[] as a copy of the GameWorld member variables, it works perfectly, and players can see each other move in real time! That would be problem solved, but I foresee that the inefficiency of copying is going to be trouble when I have dozens, if not hundreds, of positions to be serialized.

To summarize the question, what is preventing me from serializing my Position data structure directly from the GameWorld class? Why do I have to copy it right before writing it to the ObjectOutputStream?

So this works:

```
Position [] temp = new Position[4];
                for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    temp[i] = server.realWorld.diggaPoses[i];
                }
                positionOOS.writeObject(temp); 
                positionOOS.flush();
```

This does NOT work:

```
positionOOS.writeObject(server.realWorld.diggaPoses);   

positionOOS.flush();
```

To clarify, my GameWorld instance in the "server" instance is called "realWorld."

Comment: Ok.. I think this should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
positionOOS.writeObject(server.realWorld.diggaPoses);
```

Try this:

```
positionOOS.writeUnshared(server.realWorld.diggaPoses);
```

or:

```
positionOOS.reset();
positionOOS.writeObject(server.realWorld.diggaPoses);
```

See the Javadoc for why.